# Getting the Container in a ASP.NET MVC EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

I just created a custom template for all elements with an `FunctionPickerAttribute` (custom attribute that I wrote myself). Now, what the `FunctionPickerAttribute` does is simply to store the name of a method that returns a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, String>>`.

The template I created finds that attribute, finds the method (using reflection) and is then supposed to call that method upon the object. However, the problem is that `FunctionPickerAttribute` is assigned onto a property of type string, so that when I enter the FunctionPicker-template I have no idea of how to get a reference to my object.

I can find the type of the Container (using `ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType`), but I need to get a reference to the Container in some way. Is this possible? And if it is, how do I go about making it?

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do with this?

Comment: I'm creating a plugin-driven project, and one plugin needs to be able to select another plugin based on a set of criteria. For instance, the MembershipPlugin needs to be able to pick a EmailAccount from the EmailPlugin without having any knowledge about what EmailPlugin was selected prior to this, only knowing it implements a certain interface. I'd love to explain more if anyone is interested in the project (which is open-source), but doing so in this small comment-window would be impossible :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the way your doing it.

The only way to get the container is pass the entire model to your template.

If you post more of your code I could help better.  I do this type of thing often.

Comment: Well. The amount of source-code in effect is a bit to much. I've found a "working" solution though, but I don't like it. I've created my own custom Object-template, that checks if any of the properties it's displaying is a `FunctionPicker`, and if it is fires the FunctionPicker-template with the context in it's ViewData. Works, but not pretty.

Comment: Oh, an bye the way, the project can be found here: https://github.com/Alxandr/AppVisum, and here: https://github.com/Alxandr/AppVisum.Sys (2 projects in solution).